# What is the intuition behind the direct product and the direct sum of groups being identical for finite groups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I have seen the statement that the direct product of groups $G_1\otimes G_2 \otimes … \otimes G_N$ is identical to the direct sum of groups $G_1\oplus G_2 \oplus … \oplus G_N$ for finite $N$.

What is the intuition about this being true?

Comment: Direct product is usually denoted by $\times$ while $\otimes$ usually stands for tensor product.

Comment: It's true for Abelian groups only. (Or.. what is the direct sum of noncommutative groups?)

Comment: @Berci : direct sum is defined for any family of groups, in the same way as for abelian groups : it's the subgroup of the product where all but finitely many coordinates are $1$ (with multiplicative notation). It's simply not a coproduct, but it still exists

Answer (score 1):

It's basically the fact that finite *coproducts* and products coincide in the category of Abelian groups.

There's a deep connection of these coincidences with addition, as discussed [here](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/a-meditation-on-semiadditive-categories/) in details. 
Briefly, for any category with zero morphisms:

> There (naturally) is a commutative monoid structure ('addition') on the set of morphisms $A\to B$ for any objects $A,B\ $ *iff*$\ $ finite coproducts and products coincide

Now, pointwise addition of homomorphisms $f,g:A\to B$ produces again a homomorphism $A\to B\ $ (*if $B$ is commutative*), and thus it gives rise to a commutative monoid structure (with inverses, i.e. an Abelian group).